# Pass command line arguments to Bokeh server application

Tags: bokeh

I have a Bokeh server application.  I would like to pass it custom options on the command line:

```
bokeh serve /path/to/script.py --my-option foo
```

Is this possible?  Will Bokeh pass these options through somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use the `--args` command line option [described in the User's Guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html#bokeh-command-subcommands-serve). Everything you put after the `--args` option will just appear in `sys.argv` for the app code, just as you would expect with any normal python script.

Running this app:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

With this invocation:

```
bokeh serve foo.py --args -x 1 bar --baz
```

Then opening a session will result in this being printed:

```
['foo.py', '-x', '1', 'bar', '--baz']
```